# Origin of the saying: Ex Deo Nascimur, In Christo Morimur

Tags: reference-request, origin, rosicrucianism

> Ex Deo Nascimur,
>   In Christo Morimur,
>   Per Spiritum Sanctum Reviviscimus
>
> From God we are born,
>   In Christ we die,
>   (and) in (/per) the Holy Spirit we are reborn (revived)

This is an old saying that I think is attributed to the [Rosicrucians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosicrucianism).  I'm trying to back track it further as it clearly predates them by at least a millennia.

Any ideas on the origins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fama Fratemitatis

According to the *Fama Fratemitatis*, the origins of the saying appear to be from **Christian Rosenkreuz** (b.1378) who formed a small group in Germany in the early to mid 15th century for the purpose of inseminating a, "general reformation." This group created a series of *Axiomata* [Sayings] along with a secret dictionary, a mysterious wheel and a house to serve as their temple. When Rosankreuz died in 1484 he was placed in a tomb with an inscription on the vault instructing that the tomb be opened in 120yrs. When his body was exhumed in in 1604 he was found to be holding a parchment in his hands. At the bottom of that parchment was written: "Ex Deo Nascimur, In Christo Morimur, Per Spiritum Sanctum Reviviscimus."

Source: [Rosicrucianism Renewed](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ZgZoRo26y4UC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to this discussion, but of course Christian Rosenkreuz is a fictional character (the name's kind of a giveaway: Christian Rosecross), the central figure in Rosicrucian legend.

I believe the source of that exact quote is Rosicrucianism, though of course the idea of dying in Christ, being born of the Holy Spirit, etc, is something that goes very far back in Christianity, so there are probably similar formulas in Patristic and mystical writing.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).